# Turn off red light? Override read-only?

Tags: pi-3b+

I wanna turn off the red light on my raspberry pi. I have searched and found that I should run this command:

```
sudo sh -c "echo heartbeat >/sys/class/leds/led0/trigger"
```

But I get "**zsh: read-only file system: /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger**"

How do I override that?

And no, this doesn't work either:

```
echo heartbeat | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger >/dev/null
```

tee: /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger >/dev/null: Read-only file system

Comment: how is your raspberry pi OS different from a "standard" install - did you configure something without understanding it?

Comment: @JaromandaX No it's a regular installation, I would say.

Comment: `zsh` is not part of a regular install. `/sys` is not mounted readonly in a regular install - so, what did you do after you installed raspberry pi OS?